# How do I deal with this type of returned JSON in PHP?

Tags: php, json

I have an API call that's returning JSON that looks like this:

```
{"subtotal":{"amount":"0.50","currency":"USD"}}
```

I'm not sure how to access the 'amount' variable. I tried

```
$jsonObject = json_decode(returnJSON);
$amount = $jsonObject->{'subtotal'}->{'amount'}
```

but that doesn't work. How is this data accessed?

Comment: that `returnJSON` needs to be a variable containing that json string like `$returnJSON = '{"subtotal":{"amount":"0.50","currency":"USD"}}'`

Answer (score 3):

You can access it as an associative array:

```
$jsonObject = json_decode($returnJSON, true);
$amount = $jsonObject['subtotal']['amount'];
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$returnJSON = '{"subtotal":{"amount":"0.50","currency":"USD"}}';
$jsonObject = json_decode($returnJSON, true);
$amount     = $jsonObject['subtotal']['amount'];
```

or

```
$returnJSON = '{"subtotal":{"amount":"0.50","currency":"USD"}}';
$jsonObject = json_decode($returnJSON);
$amount     = $jsonObject->subtotal->amount;
```

Answer (score 1):

As opposed to all these other comments, you can also just use it as a regular object (which is `json_decode`'s default):

```
$jsonObject = json_decode($returnJSON);
$amount = (float)$jsonObject->subtotal->amount;

var_dump($amount); //float(0.50)
```

Comment: +1 for using the object syntax. json_decode($json, true); is for the assoc array.
Also i think it would be nice to explain why you added a typecast

Answer (score 0):

What does not work? What's the error message? Do you get a

> Trying to get property of non-object in MyPath\myPHPFile on line 3

error message?

In that case it's because your JSON is flawed, there's a closing bracket missing. After fixing that it works on my side to access it the way you want.

Also, don't forget to close each line with a semicolon in PHP.

Comment: -1. The answer does not fix the OP's question. The OP is trying to access it via. some messed syntax ( $jsonObject->{'subtotal'}->{'amount'}) Also does the authors json look flawed to you? The only right thing you mention is the missing semicolon...

Comment: "there's a closing bracket missing" Fixing that fixes his problem, yes. Edit: FYI OP edited that missing closing bracket in after I answered it.

Comment: did not notice it was missing. This still does not explain not taking action on the messed up syntax of php

Comment: So messed up that it still works when his JSON has no flaws? Well, that "messed up" syntax wasn't his question to begin with but to get it to work. Well, whatever.

Comment: reversed to +1 ;) i did not know that the horrid php syntax was added later on...

Answer (score 0):

All that you need is here:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php#example-3736

Check the first example.

Comment: Sorry, http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php. The web has detected my country ;)